# jQuery apply class only to offending div

Tags: jquery

I have a row of divs, all have the same classes. They display user comments on the page.

I have written an if statement to change the widths of the comments if there is less than 4.

Is there a way I can target only those divs in that one row, even if they share the same class name

**JS**

```
// if statements to sort out widths if there are < 4 comments
if(commentLength === 1){
    $('.comment').css('min-width','1453px');
}
else if(commentLength === 2){
    $('.comment').css('min-width','700px');
}
else if(commentLength === 3){
    $('.comment').css('min-width','470px');
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="commentary">
    <div class="comment">Sample commnent</div>
    <div class="comment">Sample commnent</div>
    <div class="comment">Sample commnent</div>
    <div class="comment">Sample commnent</div>
</div>
<div class="commentary">
    <div class="comment">Sample commnent</div>
    <div class="comment">Sample commnent</div>
</div>
<div class="commentary">
    <div class="comment">Sample commnent</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I am unable to test atm :( Will check tomorrow. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.commentary').each(function(){
    var $myComments = $(this).find('.comment');
    var commentLength = $myComments.length;

    if(commentLength === 1){
        $myComments.css('min-width','1453px');
    }
    else if(commentLength === 2){
        $myComments.css('min-width','700px');
    }
    else if(commentLength === 3){
        $myComments.css('min-width','470px');
    }        
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".commentary").each(function () {
   var $comments = $(this).find('.comment');
   var commentLength = $comments.length;

   //your JS code goes here, but replace $('.comment') with $comments
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jG6FB/